# Using normal java class and using spring bean doesn't work

Tags: spring

I have an utility class which doesn't have any annotation as @component

I have declared few autowired service class variables in the utility class however all of them are null when accessing inside the method

1. How to use spring beans inside utility class ?
2. Do we need to forcibly mark the utility class as "@component"?
3. I have included the utility class in the base scan packages but it doesn't work
4. Couldn't get the application context to load the service class as it returns null ? do we need to load the service class via application context

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand the concept of Spring's beans, all classes marked with `@Component` are managed by `SPRING CDI`.

@ComponentScan add to CDI only these classes that marked with @Component( or others annotation that has @Component for example @Service)

You can't use Spring beans inside simple java classes.

But if you really want you can use the following code (I don't recommend it because here you will use Spring as work aroung solution)

```
@Component
public final class BeanInjector implements ApplicationContextAware{


    private BeanInjector(){}
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public synchronized void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(final Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

}
```

And in your simple class you will use this class as follows

```
public class Pojo(
  void smth(){
   BeanInjector.getBean(ClassAnnotatedWithComponent.class);

}

)
```